# Infinite Loop whilst printing table

Tags: c++, printing, ascii

I am currently trying to print a table of users which have an ID, a username and a password. I accomplished making the board looking like this:

```
ID|Username|Password
--+--------+-----------
1 |jtar    |123456
2 |mordecai|11111111111
```

As you can see, I want to be able to scale the table's cells to the maximum size of each column's contents. The thing is, I get an infinite loop of printing spaces for some reason. I have pinpointed the location of the loop in my code below. I also have added comments for further clarification.

As it stands, I calculate how many spaces should be added after each of the user's data are printed. If the data string size is less than the appropriate matrix column tag (i.e. if the the size of the username is less than the size of the string "Username"), then print the difference of sizes worth of spaces.
If now the size of the data is longer than the size of the appropriate tag, print the difference of the maximum data from each column size and the current user's data size.

I added an or operation in each for loop as to avoid making an if-else statement and two for loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class User {
  int id;
  string username;
  string password;
  public:
  //Constructor-Destructor
  User(const int _id, const string _username, const string _password) : id(_id),
  username(_username), password(_password) { }
  ~User(){}

  //Accessors- Mutators
  int getId() {return id;}
  string getUsername() {return username;}
  string getPassword() {return password;}
};

const string intToStr(const int target)
{
    stringstream stream;
    stream << target;
    return stream.str();
}

int main() {
    vector<User*> userList;
    int maxIdLength = 0, maxUsernameLength = 0, maxPasswordLength = 0;
    //create users
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        userList.push_back(new User(i, "user" + i, "genericpass"));
    }

    //find maximum lengths
    for (vector<User*>::iterator it = userList.begin(); (it != userList.end()); it++) {

        if (maxIdLength < intToStr( (*it)->getId() ).size())
            maxIdLength = intToStr((*it)->getId()).size();

        if (maxUsernameLength < (*it)->getUsername().size())
            maxUsernameLength = (*it)->getUsername().size();

        if (maxPasswordLength < (*it)->getPassword().size())
            maxPasswordLength = (*it)->getPassword().size();
    }

    //print headlines
    cout << "ID";
    for (int i = 0; i < maxIdLength - 2; i++)
        cout << " ";
    cout << "|Username";
    for (int i = 0; i < maxUsernameLength - 8; i++)
        cout << " ";
    cout << "|Password";
    for (int i = 0; i < maxPasswordLength - 8; i++)
        cout << " ";
    cout<<endl;

    //print cosmetic line
    cout << "--";
    for (int i = 0; i < maxIdLength - 2; i++)
        cout << "-";
    cout << "+--------";
    for (int i = 0; i < maxUsernameLength - 8; i++)
        cout << "-";
    cout << "+--------";
    for (int i = 0; i < maxPasswordLength - 8; i++)
        cout << "-";
    cout << endl;

    for (vector<User*>::iterator it = userList.begin(); (it != userList.end()); it++) {//start printing the users
    //Infinite Loop bug in the second conditional argument of the for loops
            cout << (*it)->getId();//id

            for (int i = 0; ( i < maxIdLength - intToStr((*it)->getId()).size() ) || ( i < ( 2 - intToStr((*it)->getId()).size() ) ); i++)
                cout << " ";
            cout << "|" << (*it)->getUsername();//username

            for (int i = 0; ( i < ( maxUsernameLength - ((*it)->getUsername()).size() ) ) || ( i < (8 - ( (*it)->getUsername() ).size()) ); i++)
                cout << " ";
            cout << "|" << (*it)->getPassword();//password
            for (int i = 0; i < maxPasswordLength - (*it)->getPassword().size() || i < 8 - (*it)->getPassword().size(); i++)
                cout << " ";
        cout<<endl;
    }

    while(!userList.empty()) {
        delete userList.back();
        userList.pop_back();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you have your "infinite" loop? Can you please point it out in the code you show? Or better yet, try to remove all unrelated code to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, have you tried to use a debugger to step through the code, line by line, to see what it does that you didn't expected it to do?

Comment: I pointed out that the infinite loop is produced in hte second conditional argument of the loops below. Also, this is the minimal version, the actual code is much larger. This is the minimal,complete and verifiable Example

Comment: @JohnLannister did you even try to do basic debugging ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes I did, that's why I am here, because it got nowhere. I even tried making the code more compact only to be spurned...

Comment: We don't need to see the code for the output. We don't really need all 20 users, so we don't need the loops adding them or calculating the max lengths, a MCVE could hard-code it. If all three loops are "infinite" then we only need one. Most of the code you show doesn't add anything.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added all that to help show the board.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, the compiler should complain, because you are comparing `int` with `size_t` which is unsigned, so `2 - xxx.size()` is unsigned and if the size is larger than 2, it becomes a large number.

see [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fac625eaccd48c5e)

A possible solution is `static_cast` of the size to int.

Comment: `Normally, the compiler should complain` and it does, unless you suppress the warnings manually

Comment: I use VS so that's why it did not complain.

Comment: check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y92ktdf2.aspx) if you want to be warned instead of hunting weird logic.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I can detect is that you are adding the `int i` to the rvalue `string user`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    userList.push_back(new User(i, "user" + i, "genericpass"));
}
```

you should use `itoa`, to cast i into a `string` value